# FIX Messages Tag appears more than once

Tags: c#, fix-protocol

I am working with Fix 4.3 and have two issues, if I can get one issue resolved it should eliminate the second.

However... I am using QuickFIX example files as a way of starting off my project, I am able to connect to the target machine, and get marketdata out, however..  it returns many results.

the first of which is what I am after and after that I would like it to stop polling for information.

the second issue is I am getting the notification Message X Rejected: Tag appears more than once (field=6215)

Looking in the code this is the tenor value, is I make any change to this then the application fails and doesn't get any FIX information.

I would be grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction to help me resolve this.

This is my cfg file with the target and sender compid removed.

I am using STunnel to make my connection hence the socket looking at localhost.

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=2
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=log
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=../../../../spec/fix/FIX43.xml
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
SocketConnectPort=1337
LogoutTimeout=5
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y

[SESSION]
# inherit ConnectionType, ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from default
BeginString=FIX.4.3
SenderCompID=XXXX
TargetCompID=XXXX
HeartBtInt=3000
```

thanks

Simon

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you have not updated your data dictionary XML file to match any customizations that your counterparty has made.

6215 is a custom tag of some sort, and I bet it's inside a repeating group.  However, I suspect that, in your DD, you haven't added it inside the group.  Therefore, when the engine comes to it, it says "6215 doesn't belong to this group, so the group must just have ended", and it thinks 6215 is outside the group.  When this happens the second time, you get your error.

Fix your DD so it matches your counterparty's specifications and this should go away.

Comment: I will take a look at this this morning.